# Attempting To obtain the maximum number of consecutive wins in football database

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So I'm trying to get the longest win streak from my football database. I know there are a lot of similar questions on stack overflow but most of the solutions just end up with adding the total wins for each team which isn't what im trying to get.

My goal is to get longest win streak that a team has ever had. Essentially if team1 played 10 games and within those  10 games won 6 times in a row and then lost 1 and won 3 in a row, then the consecutive wins command should return that team1 had a max win streak of 6.

The code I have is displaying the total number of wins for each player though, which is not what im trying to get.

```
MATCH (T1:Team)-[m:Match]-(:Team)
with T1, m
ORDER BY m.round ASC
WITH T1,
REDUCE(initial = {wins: 0, max_wins: 0}, matches IN COLLECT(m) | 
CASE WHEN (T1 = startNode(matches) AND (matches.ft_home_score > matches.ft_away_score))
OR (T1 = endNode(matches) AND (matches.ft_away_score > matches.ft_home_score))
THEN {wins: initial.wins + 1, max_wins: CASE WHEN initial.wins + 1 > initial.max_wins THEN initial.wins + 1 ELSE initial.max_wins END}
ELSE initial
END).max_wins AS successive_wins
return T1.name AS Team, successive_wins ORDER BY successive_wins DESC
```

The result of the code above is:

```
Team    successive_wins
"Manchester City FC"    32
"Manchester United FC"  25
"Tottenham Hotspur FC"  23
"Chelsea FC"    21
"Liverpool FC"  21
"Arsenal FC"    19
"Burnley FC"    14
"Everton FC"    13
"Newcastle United FC"   12
"Leicester City FC" 12
```

I think im doing something wrong with my REDUCE statement but not entirely sure what exactly :D

Comment: can you share the model of your graph ? (nodes, rels and properties of them ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have APOC procedures, you can use a collection split procedure to help out.

```
MATCH (T1:Team)-[m:Match]-()
with T1, m
ORDER BY m.round ASC
WITH T1, collect(NOT (T1 = startNode(m) XOR (m.ft_home_score > m.ft_away_score)) AND NOT m.ft_home_score = m.ft_away_score) as results
CALL apoc.coll.split(results, false) YIELD value
WITH T1, max(size(value)) as successive_wins
RETURN T1.name AS Team, successive_wins 
ORDER BY successive_wins DESC
```

Some notes on this one.

I'm using NOT ... XOR to implement XNOR, which just makes the boolean logic a bit easier (both terms are true or both terms are false), though we do need to throw in one last check to ensure we don't count ties.

By collecting booleans for ordered outcomes (true if win, false otherwise) and splitting on false, we get on each row a list of consecutive trues, or consecutive wins, and by getting the one with the largest size, we get the maximum number of consecutive wins per team.

Comment: Thanks for help! Is there anyway of not using APOC though?

Comment: The Cypher for that isn't pretty. cybersam has an answer to a similar question with a [pure cypher approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53506808/92359) that should be what you're looking for, look at the reduce() usage in the RETURN.