# Finding the most consecutive wins in a rugby league

Tags: neo4j

Suppose Rugby league results are given by this kind of data:

```
Date, Round, Home Team, Visitor Team, Result
18/10/2018, 1, ABC, XYZ, 30-20
18/10/2018, 1, PQR, ABC, 13-12
```

Can someone shed a light on how to model the above data to find out the team with the most consecutive wins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED]

If we alter the format of your CSV data to make it easier to import (by trimming excess whitespace, and changing to a more standard date format), like this (with a few extra changes to make the example more interesting):

```
Date,Round,Home Team,Visitor Team,Result
2018-10-18,1,ABC,XYZ,30-20
2018-10-18,2,ABC,PQR,28-12
2018-10-19,1,PQR,ABC,13-12
```

Then we can import the data like this (`MERGE` is used instead of `CREATE`, to avoid creating duplicate `Team` nodes):

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///data.csv' AS row
WITH row, SPLIT(row.Result, '-') AS scores
MERGE (h:Team {name: row.`Home Team`})
MERGE (v:Team {name: row.`Visitor Team`})
CREATE (h)<-[:HOME_TEAM {score: scores[0]}]-(g:Game {date: DATE(row.Date), round: row.Round})-[:AWAY_TEAM {score: scores[1]}]->(v)
```

And we can use this query to return the team with the highest number of consecutive wins:

```
MATCH (t:Team)<-[r]-(g:Game)-[r2]->(t2)
WITH t, r.score > r2.score AS isWin ORDER BY g.date, g.round
RETURN t, REDUCE(s = {max: 0, c: 0, prev:false}, w IN COLLECT(isWin) |
  CASE WHEN w
    THEN {
      c: CASE WHEN s.prev THEN s.c+1 ELSE 1 END,
      max: CASE WHEN s.max <= s.c
             THEN CASE WHEN s.prev
               THEN s.c+1
               ELSE CASE WHEN s.max = 0 THEN 1 ELSE s.max END END
             ELSE s.max END,
      prev: w}
    ELSE {c: 0, max: s.max, prev: w} END).max AS maxConsecutiveWins
ORDER BY maxConsecutiveWins DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The `MATCH` pattern does not specify any relationship types, so `r` will match both `HOME_TEAM` and `AWAY_TEAM` relationships.

The `WITH` clause calculates the win statistics for every game played by every team, and orders them by `date` and `round`.

Since the `RETURN` clause uses the [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/) `COLLECT` (within the [REDUCE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/list/#functions-reduce) function), the `t` variable is used as the aggregation `grouping key`. This causes the `REDUCE` function to process all the ordered win statistics for *one team at a time*.

The `REDUCE` function's `accumulator`, `s`, is a map with 3 properties :

- `max` is a count of the *maximum* consecutive wins discovered thus far.
- `c` is the number of consecutive wins for the *current* sequence of wins.
- `prev` is the win statistic for the *previous* game.

Since Cypher has no `IF` clause, the `CASE` clause is used for logical branching. (Note: the `CASE` clause can only return a value -- it cannot execute any read/write operations on the DB). The various `CASE` clauses in this query serve the purpose of updating the `accumulator` appropriately while iterating through each game, in order.

When the `REDUCE` function is done with all the games for a team, the `RETURN` clause takes the `max` value of the returned map and assigns it to the `maxConsecutiveWins` variable.

The last `ORDER BY` clause sorts all the `maxConsecutiveWins` values in descending order, and the `LIMIT` clause just allows the first one to be returned (the one with the highest value), along with its corresponding team.

The result, with the above data, would be:

```
╒══════════════╤════════════════════╕
│"t"           │"maxConsecutiveWins"│
╞══════════════╪════════════════════╡
│{"name":"ABC"}│2                   │
└──────────────┴────────────────────┘
```

*NOTE: Given the complexity of the `CASE` clauses, you should test the above query with all possible edge cases if you actually plan to use it.*

Comment: Could you please explain further the answer CQL ?

Comment: Thanks. Does it really need 'max' variable also ? Why can't do only with variable 'c' ? ex: do the count for c if previous match lost reset 'c' to '0'

Comment: `max` is needed, since a team can have a sequence of wins followed by losses/ties, followed by another sequence of wins, and so forth. Any sequence can be the longest. Without keeping track of the `max` found, your result would inappropriately always return the length of the *last* sequence of wins.