# how to display the team with the most consecutive “win”. in an epl match neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This question is a follow up to the answer given here [Finding the most consecutive wins in a rugby league](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53506119/finding-the-most-consecutive-wins-in-a-rugby-league)
by @cybersam

My program is for an EPL match.
but my database structure is exactly the same

my problem is this doesn't give the required output. 
i tried this on my database and it gives the output as - Manchester united with 14 consecutive wins. 
its meant to be 18.

This is the data set
and the tried code

```
Round,Date,Team 1,FT,HT,Team 2
1,(Fri) 11 Aug 2017 (32),Arsenal FC,4-3,2-2,Leicester City FC



MATCH (t:Team)<-[r]-(g:Match)-[r2]->(t2)
WITH t, r.Ftaway_goal > r2.Fthome_goal AS isWin ORDER BY g.Date, g.Round
RETURN t, REDUCE(s = {max: 0, c: 0, prev:false}, w IN COLLECT(isWin) |
  CASE WHEN w
    THEN {
      c: CASE WHEN s.prev THEN s.c+1 ELSE 1 END,
      max: CASE WHEN s.max <= s.c
         THEN CASE WHEN s.prev
           THEN s.c+1
           ELSE CASE WHEN s.max = 0 THEN 1 ELSE s.max END END
         ELSE s.max END,
  prev: w}
ELSE {c: 0, max: s.max, prev: w} END).max AS maxConsecutiveWins

 order by maxConsecutiveWins DESC
 limit 1
```

The case part of the code i understand but i cant seem to figure out why some wins aren't being checked against it. 
initially i thought it was an issue with it only counting the away_team matches but it isn't. 
Please help. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure is not identical to the one in the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53506119/finding-the-most-consecutive-wins-in-a-rugby-league).

The `Ftaway_goal` and `Fthome_goal` properties have different names. Therefore, your query's `r.Ftaway_goal > r2.Fthome_goal` test is only considering away games as possible wins.

If you used a consistent property name, like `goal`, for both home and away games, then a `r.goal > r2.goal` test would take both types of games into consideration.

Comment: yes its not identical, but the structure of my database is modeled after that just with different names and dataset. i already have nine other queries running on this structure, is there a way to work around this please. i tried doing 

    WITH t, (r.Ftaway_goal > r2.Fthome_goal OR r.Fthome_goal > r2.Ftaway_goal  ) AS isWin ORDER BY g.Date, g.Round

but this just ends up giving the total number of wins not consecutive wins

Comment: also the total number of consecutive wins for Manchester City away games alone isn't 14, its less than that. which is why i'm more confused. i cant understand why the output is 14. if i remove the limit the answers for other teams are also just as wrong. i cant tell the logic behind why the code gives the output it does

Comment: If you don't want to change your property names (which may not be difficult, depending on your other queries), one workaround is to just add an additional `goal`  property to your `Team` nodes.

Comment: ah yes i realized the fundamental difference, been able to correct the structure. works great now. thank you